# Voltage divider not working

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider

I have been experimenting on transistors recently with this [simulation](https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/2196349-transistor-experiment) , it works as expected and all make sense except the `V1` value.

In the schematics below I used a voltage devider between `R1` and `R2` and therefore I was expecting `V1` to be half of the source voltage minus `VBE`, which should be `9/2 - 0.7 = 3.8V`

[image: ![Schematics]

However when the potentiometer is at 0 `V1` is 2.77V

[image: ![![![Potentiometer at 0ohm]

But when it's at 170Kohm `V1` changes to 4.22V

[image: ![![Potentiometer at 170Kohm]

Why does `V1` change like that instead of being constant 3.8V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because current flows into the base of the transistor, causing the voltage divider to "droop". Basically, a voltage divider only behaves as you expect when no current is drawn or sourced from the middle node. As more current is drawn, the voltage at the middle of the voltage divider drifts further away from "what you expect".

Your base current Ib has to come from somewhere, and it is upsetting your voltage divider.

Also, if you redraw your schematic to match convention, it will be a lot easier to understand and refer to. Some pointers:

- Flip the battery right side up: positive voltage on top.
- Use ground symbols instead of tying everything together.
- Try to keep the "more positive" side of a component above the "less positive" side.
- Eliminate the meters, they simply muddle things up, and conventionally we refer to current through components and voltages across components or referenced to ground.
- Typically, NPN transistors are drawn with the collector on top and emitter on the bottom.

With these changes in mind, here's how your schematic might look:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr2HaA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now instead of referring to things like \$V_1\$, which is hard to figure out where it is, you can simply say \$V_{R2}\$, which is the voltage across R2, and hence, the voltage of the voltage divider. Consider that if a current flows through R3, this current must also flow through R1 (or R2), which changes the voltage across R1 and R2. As R3 increases, less current flows through R3. Consider an extreme: if R3 was infinite, no current would flow, and \$V_{R2}\$ would be 4.5V.

Also, as @Sparky256 has pointed out, you are putting the LED on the emitter of Q1, which complicates this circuit. Typically, to drive an LED with an NPN transistor, you would place the LED on the collector of the transistor.

Comment: @unit128_t. The OP also has a load on the emitter, the LED D1. That just complicates the divider even more, as the gain of T1 is very important.

Comment: But why does V1 increase when Rpot1 increase? and shouldn't the current IE be drawn from the collector?

Comment: @Sparky256 I expanded my answer, hopefully addressing a little bit about what you pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: @razzak I have expanded my answer considerably, particularly wrt the current through R3, hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: @uint128_t. Good idea, as the LED is a very non-linear load and should be on the collector in series with a 1K resistor (longer battery life). Now the OP can use this circuit to see how transistor gain affects his readings if one has a high Hfe, low Hfe, darlington, etc.

Comment: @uint128_t Thanks you very much for the explanation and the tips on drawing schematics.